# JQuery - Dynamic elements not recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

JQuery not recognizing the dynamically added data of the table. The first two button below the sample label function well, which i declared as a static markup just to test and it works, but the button with the same class in the table not function. Im so nuts with this problem.

```
<a class='btnView' href='#viewModal' data-toggle'modal' =value='FA-0000000'><i class='icon-eye'></i></a>
```

**loadTable.js**

```
var base_url = window.location.origin;

$(document).ready(function(){
    url = base_url+"/codeigniter/index.php/AssistanceMonitoringModule/assistanceMonitoring/loadTbodyHome";
    alert("loadtable.js");
    $.ajax(
        {
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        success: function(data){

            $("#loadTbodyHome").html(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("XHR:"+xhr.status+"Error:"+thrownError);
          }

        });

    $('#searchFromHomeTable').keyup(function(){
        url = base_url+"/codeigniter/index.php/AssistanceMonitoringModule/assistanceMonitoring/loadTbodyHomeSearch";
        //alert('pumasok');
        search = $("#searchFromHomeTable").val();
        $.ajax(
        {
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        data: "toSearch="+search,
        success: function(data){
            //alert(data);
            $("#loadTbodyHome").html('');
            $("#loadTbodyHome").html(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("XHR:"+xhr.status+"Error:"+thrownError);
          }

        });
    });



  });
```

**dataModal.js**

```
var base_url = window.location.origin;

$(document).ready(function(){
alert("datamodal.js");

$(".btnView").click(function(){
 alert($(this).attr('value'));

    url = base_url+"/codeigniter/index.php/AssistanceMonitoringModule/assistanceMonitoring/viewInfo";

        $.ajax(
        {
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        data: "ID="+$(this).attr('value'),
        success: function(data){
            //alert(data);
            //alert(data);
            $("#viewModalBody").html('');
            $("#viewModalBody").html(data);
            $("#viewModal").attr('aria-hidden',false);
            $("#viewModal").fadeIn();
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("XHR:"+xhr.status+"Error:"+thrownError);
          }

        });

});

});
```

Is the jquery functions not recognizing the newly added markup if its already declared? 
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Look for "event delegation".

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/   Look for "Delegated events" within the linked page

Answer (score 4):

You need to use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** for dynamically loaded elements:

```
$(document).on('click','.btnView',function(){
    // Your code here
});
```

Please note that your HTML for the button is also invalid, you need to remove `=` before `value` attribute and I'd suggest you to use `data-*` attribute instead:

```
<a class='btnView' href='#viewModal' data-toggle'modal' data-value='FA-0000000'><i class='icon-eye'></i></a>
```